# Command requires file, avoid creating temporary file

Tags: bash, process-substitution

`<()` doesn't seem to do what I expect.

This command requires a text file (it's JLinkExe, the text file contains commands for JLinkExe to run. But that shouldn't matter).

```
JLinkExe -CommanderScript <scriptfile>
```

I need to create the files dynamically, since their content depend on what I'm currently trying to achieve.

My current solution is to create a temporary file, fill it with content with `printf`, then call the JLinkExe command with that temporary file.

I have a feeling that this should be achievable with `<()`, but I don't succeed.

This doesn't work:

```
JLinkExe -CommanderScript <(printf "ShowEmuList\nexit\n")
```

I was expecting `<()` to create a temporary file descriptor, with the content of the file being the string. It works with `cat`, but JLinkExe complains the it cannot read the command file.

Am I wrong, or is it just that JLinkExe is stupid (it doesn't take stdin)?

Comment: From their wiki it appears it **needs** a file: `-CommanderScript <ScriptPath>  Selects a J-Link Commander Command file which contains the commands for the batch mode.`

Comment: Maybe `JLinkExe` expects the file to be seekable?

Comment: @MrShunz: so `<()` doesn't fake a file? I thought that's what it did, and that the application wouldn't be able to tell.

Comment: @Gauthier looks like Kamil is right. Probably `JLinkExe` needs the file to be seekable.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense! And I guess zsh's `=()` would make it, but I don't want to require zsh.